# recyclerview scrollbar stuttering

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have this problem demonstrated in [this video](https://youtu.be/-HASTtKnZg8), why is that?
setHasFixedSize doesn't solve the problem, neither does setHasStableIds, also, Ichanged the scrollbar style so you can see it properly, but the problem occurs with the default style too.

here's my code:

adapter

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HadithViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Hadith currentHadith = ahadith.get(position);
    final Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
    /*number*/
    holder.numTextView.setText(Utils.ARABIC_NUMBER_FORMAT.format(position + 1));

        /*text*/
    final String text = currentHadith.text();
    holder.hadithTextView.setText(text);

    /*buttons*/
    holder.moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.moreBtn);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_hadith_options, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.copy_item:
                            UTILS.copyHadith(context, currentHadith);
                            break;

                        case R.id.share_item:
                            UTILS.shareHadith(context, currentHadith);
                            break;

                        case R.id.lookup_item:
                            UTILS.webSearch(context, currentHadith);
                            break;

                        case R.id.save_item:
                            DBS_MANAGER.saveHadith(currentHadith);
                            Snackbar.make(((ResultsActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.recycler_view),
                                    R.string.removed_notification,
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();

        }
    });
}
```

activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    layout="@layout/recycler_view"/></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

recyclerview.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/saved_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the various items in your `RecyclerView` have different sizes (i.e. heights).

The scrollbar is sized and positioned based on what the `RecyclerView` is currently showing and the number of items off-screen above and below what is currently showing. The `RecyclerView` guesses that all items are approximately the same height and draws the scrollbar accordingly.

Imagine that your `RecyclerView` is showing one really really tall item right now, and has one really short item above it and five really short items below it. As far as the view knows, all the items are the same size, so the scrollbar will only be 1/6 - 2/6 of the way down the screen... until you scroll those really short items into view.

Comment: So whats the solution? Why does scrollbar even change its thumb hight?

Comment: I do not believe it is fixable (unless you can make your `RecyclerView` items all approximately the same height). The scrollbar changes height because it needs to accurately represent how much scrolling is yet to come. A very short scrollbar indicates that there's a lot more content, while a very tall scrollbar indicates that there's only a little more content.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is a huge issue.

Comment: 39:37 in this video discusses how to solve the problem for ListView. Perhaps there is a solution I'm not aware of for RecyclerView. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70